# Payflow Pro API for retrieving reference transactions

Tags: payflowpro

We have integrated Payflow pro payment gateway into our website and processing payment requests using Payflow as payment gateway and storing payflow transaction id as a part of response into our database.

We need to retrieve transaction history for specific transaction Id as shown in PayPal manager.

So please suggest me appropriate API for retrieving Reference transactions on basis of specific transaction Id as soon as possible.

Looking forward for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You could get information back about transactions a couple of different ways.  You could either use the inquiry by setting `TRXTYPE=I` or by using the [Reporting API's](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_reporting_guide.pdf).